# Where is the code for the EDML generated Models?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have built a data driven model by dragging my tables onto the empty designer of an edml. I know that I can establish a datacontext around my model, and that I can access each table as though it were a class, but where is the code for each of these models?

I ask because I want to add validation to the setters of each property on the class itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for a `.dbml` file on the root level of your project. Under that file, you will see a file called `<someDB>.designer.cs`.

However, (and you'll see this at the top of the designer file as well), you don't really want to make any changes to the classes in this file.

```
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
```

If you want to make additions, you should look into creating `Partial` classes that extend the functionality of the generated classes.

Here is a sample partial class that I created to handle my validations:

```
 namespace ETL_Framework_UI
{
[MetadataType(typeof(DataObjectMD))]
public partial class DATA_OBJECT:IValidatableObject
{

    public class DataObjectMD
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="The object name is required")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Name cannot exceed 50 characters")]
        public string OBJECT_NAME { get; set; }

    }
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        ETLDbDataContext db = new ETLDbDataContext();
        var field = new[] { "OBJECT_NAME" };
        var param = db.DATA_OBJECTs.SingleOrDefault(r => r.OBJECT_NAME == OBJECT_NAME && r.OBJECT_ID != OBJECT_ID);
        if (param != null)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Object name is already in use. ", field);
}
```

**NOTE** Your partial class must be defined in the same namespace that you see at the top of your `designer.cs` file.

Comment: This would be the first time I have ever used a partial class. Man there is some code in there I have never seen!

Comment: There's some pretty cool stuff out there. Check out these PluralSight videos on the right side: http://www.asp.net/mvc . It's got some great tutorials on Validation and other MVC concepts

Comment: Thanks for the link. Its the first time i have ever seen "yield" being used. What does it mean!?

Comment: MSDN is better at explaining it that I would be :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You do not want to edit the auto-generated classes themselves, this will lead to huge problems if you ever need to generate them again.  You want to use partial classes with DataAnnotations instead.  This way your validation/extra rules will be forever separated and easier to maintain.

[Entity framework + validation annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125644/entity-framework-validation-annotation)

Comment: Thanks a lot of the link. I didnt know such a thing exists, and now I know what some of the code Rondel (above) was talking about in his example.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to add validation maybe Entity Framework Code First is a better solution.

Comment: Can you explain why? Ive always wondered why I should choose entity over linq to sql. I know ltos is better for sql server environments.

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing why, too. I'm not aware of any frequently-used validation systems that don't work as well with L2S as EF.

Comment: No partial classes are required. You have all in one place. More about advantages of EF code first http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

Comment: @MegaHerz Genius. Thats exactly what I was hoping for.